# Getting error event.js:174 throw er; everytime I save any scss file

Tags: node.js, events, compiler-errors, gulp, unhandled

[Here's a Screen Shot of the error event.js:174](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8g1.jpg)

I did a lot of research and googled a lot. I tried uninstalling and re-installing everything. Made new files again but still no luck. I tried on my laptop and it works smoothly without any errors. I am using Windows 7 64 bit desktop.

Am I doing anything wrong in Gulp? Here's the gulp code:

```js
const gulp        = require('gulp');
const sass        = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const minify = require('gulp-minify');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
const postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
//const webp = require('gulp-webp');
const log = require('fancy-log');
const g = require("gulp-load-plugins")();
const purgecss = require('gulp-purgecss');
const critical = require('critical').stream;


gulp.task('purgecss', () => {
    return gulp.src('./dist/css/*.css')
        .pipe(purgecss({
            content: ["./dist/*.html"]
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/purged'))
})

// Extract Media Queries & Make Seperate CSS Files
gulp.task("extractmedia", function() {
    gulp.src("./dist/css/*.css")
        .pipe(g.extractMediaQueries())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css/"));
});

// CSS Tasks
gulp.task('css-compile', function() {
    gulp.src('scss/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'nested'}).on('error', sass.logError))
      .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ['last 10 versions'],
        cascade: false
      }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css/'));
});

gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
    gulp.src(['./dist/css/*.css', '!dist/css/*.min.css'])
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'))
});


// JavaScript Tasks
gulp.task('js-build', function() {

    const plugins = getJSModules();

    return gulp.src(plugins.modules)
      .pipe(concat('modules.js'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'));
  });
  
  gulp.task('js-minify', function() {
    gulp.src(['./dist/js/*.js', '!dist/js/*.min.js'])
      .pipe(minify({
        ext:{
          src:'.js',
          min:'.min.js'
        },
        noSource: true,
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
  });
  



// Image Compression
gulp.task('img-compression', function() {
gulp.src('./img/*')
    .pipe(imagemin([
    imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
    imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
    imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5}),
    imagemin.svgo({
        plugins: [
        {removeViewBox: true},
        {cleanupIDs: false}
        ]
    })
    ]))
    //.pipe(webp())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img'));
});

// Generate & Inline Critical-path CSS
gulp.task('critical', function () {
    return gulp.src('./dist/*.html')
        .pipe(critical({base: './dist/', inline: true, css: ['./dist/css/app.min.css']}))
        .on('error', function(err) { log.error(err.message); })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("dist/scss/*.scss")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream({match: '**/*.css'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer({ browsers: [
          'Chrome >= 35',
          'Firefox >= 38',
          'Edge >= 12',
          'Explorer >= 10',
          'iOS >= 8',
          'Safari >= 8',
          'Android 2.3',
          'Android >= 4',
          'Opera >= 12']})]))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(cleanCSS())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
});


// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        injectChanges: true,
        server: "./dist"
    });

    gulp.watch("dist/scss/*.scss", ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("dist/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


gulp.task('default', ['serve'], function() {
    gulp.watch("scss/**/*.scss", ['css-compile']);
    gulp.watch(["dist/css/*.css", "!dist/css/*.min.css"], ['minify-css']);
    gulp.watch("js/**/*.js", ['js-build']);
    gulp.watch(["dist/js/*.js", "!dist/js/*.min.js"], ['js-minify']);

    gulp.watch("**/*", {cwd: './img/'}, ['img-compression']);
});

function getJSModules() {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./js/modules.js')];
    return require('./js/modules');
  }
```

Please Help I am Stuck. As every time I save scss file I get this error all of a sudden which sucks hell lot of time for me to develop further. Sometimes it works fine but after 3-4 save file it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

**Found the Solution:** It was all about the Folder Permissions. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please elaborate on the solution as I'm having the same problem right now. Thank You!